# SVM: Cross Validation Parameter Search Returns Constant Accuracies

Tags: python, machine-learning, parameters, scikit-learn, svm

I used a parameter search on SVM on a dataset of 469 training examples and 136 features, with labels {1,2,3,4}, using Scikit-Learn for a classification problem.

I expected the results for each SVM implementation to be unique with their respective parameters, but got something different.

The results are the following: for the 'rbf' kernel, the accuracy is constantly at 27.5 %, while the accuracy for the 'poly' kernel is always at 90.8%, regardless of the parameters.

```
Score: 0.27505330490405117  Parameters: {'C': 1, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
Score: 0.27505330490405117  Parameters: {'C': 1, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
Score: 0.27505330490405117  Parameters: {'C': 10, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
Score: 0.27505330490405117  Parameters: {'C': 10, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
Score: 0.27505330490405117  Parameters: {'C': 100, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
Score: 0.27505330490405117  Parameters: {'C': 100, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
Score: 0.27505330490405117  Parameters: {'C': 1000, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
Score: 0.27505330490405117  Parameters: {'C': 1000, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
Score: 0.908315565031983    Parameters: {'C': 1, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'poly'}
Score: 0.908315565031983    Parameters: {'C': 1, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'poly'}
Score: 0.908315565031983    Parameters: {'C': 10, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'poly'}
Score: 0.908315565031983    Parameters: {'C': 10, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'poly'}
Score: 0.908315565031983    Parameters: {'C': 100, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'poly'}
Score: 0.908315565031983    Parameters: {'C': 100, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'poly'}
Score: 0.908315565031983    Parameters: {'C': 1000, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'poly'}
Score: 0.908315565031983    Parameters: {'C': 1000, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'poly'}
```

I have reason to think that the data and their respective labels has to be normalized or worked on. What are possible reasons for the results to behave so?

The code for my parameter search is the following:

```
tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-3, 1e-4],
                     'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]},
                    {'kernel': ['poly'], 'gamma': [1e-3, 1e-4],
                     'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}]
svc = SVC()                    # From Scikit-Learn
clf = GridSearchCV(svc, tuned_parameters)
clf.fit(X_temporary, y_cue_temporary)
means = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
parameters = clf.cv_results_['params']
for mean, param in zip(means, parameters):
    print("Score: {}\tParameters: {}".format(mean, param))
```

Comment: It's hard to debug without a [mcve] but could it be related to the large number of features relative to your observations? Every model you build has the same(ish) decision boundaries. Can you try to get more samples? Or reduce your dimensionality?

Comment: Always normlize the data when working with svms of any kind. Have you done that?